# Not sure if I should be using a real time database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Currently having trouble displaying all highscores from my firebase realtime database. At the moment I'm only displaying "live" scores.

I am currently making a score board, where the top 50 scores and their usernames are displayed in a table. This works fine. However I am unsure as to whether I should be using a Real-Time database.

You see, when I do a fresh build on my physical device and create a new user, the user is saved into the Firebase database and when I achieve a new score and push to display highscore users, my new user is rightfully there with their score.

If I log out (but am still within the app) and register with a new user, and then play again (with the new user), and then I click to see the highscores leaderboard again I can now see both of the users I have created, with their scores. GREAT!

I can check the Authentication part of firebase, and sure enough, my users are in there with their email and passwords etc. And I can check their highscores on the Real-Time database. All is well.

However, when I delete the app from my device or even push it into the background, and then do a fresh build, or re-open the app. The authentication details (password, username, email) are still there, but when I open the Real-Time database, there is no data there.

Consequently, when I click to see the highscores leaderboard, there is nothing to show. Is this because I should not be using a realtime database, is it only  displaying “live/recent data” and doesn't actually store the data I want permanently. Should I be using SQL or something else?

This is the code to add my highscore to my database......

```
func addingScoreToFB() {

  let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser
  let highScore = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: highScoreIdentifier)
  let recentScore = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: recentScoreIdentifier)

  if let userID = currentUser?.uid {
  let userDB = Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(userID)
  if recentScore > highScore {
      let highSDictionary = ["highScore":self.recentScores.last!]
            userDB.updateChildValues(highSDictionary as Any as! [AnyHashable : Any], withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in // Adding Score

   if let err = err {
      print(err)
   }
   })
  }
 }
}
```

This is my code to display the scores.....

```
func retrieveUserData() {

    let postsRef = self.ref.child("Users")
    let query = postsRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "highScore").queryLimited(toLast: 50)
    query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        for child in snapshot.children {
           let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
           let dict = snap.value as! [String: Any]
           let name = dict["username"] as! String
           let score = dict["highScore"] as! Int
           let aScore = ScoreClass(withName: name, andScore: score)
           self.scoresArray.insert(aScore, at: 0)
        }
     self.topScoresTableView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

In summary I would like to be able to see the top 50 scores of every user in the database of all time, but I am currently only seeing the recent ones on a new build.

Comment: Real quick, is there a particular reason you're not using Firesore instead?

Comment: Where in the code are you calling `retrieveUserData()`?

Comment: @Jen Person

I am calling it in viewDidLoad() as the entire VC is the leaderboard.

Comment: @bsod I'm not sure why, is Firesore better?

Comment: You sound like you're in the early stages of all of this so if I were you, I'd rip out RTDB and install Firestore. Firestore is the future of Google's NoSQL, not RTDB. I also recommend this bc Firestore's documentation is very straightforward and is a good way to jump into and learn basic NoSQL, which is ostensibly what you need. And to answer your question, you've definitely chosen the right data solution, you just have an implementation problem.

Comment: @bsod ok thanks for the tip, that's quite frustrating but oh well. I will look into it tomorrow. I was hoping to get around it somehow but if I can't then I will do what you say.

Comment: Don't be discouraged, be excited that you get to learn something new and cutting edge. Because Firestore is the future of serverless, and whether you use it or not, it's a good framework to know. If you have time today, watch a couple of YouTube videos with Rick Houlihan, a NoSQL guru who works for AWS. Try to understand as much as you can about NoSQL before you start writing code.

Comment: @bsod ok great, thanks for the tips